# How to add a short pause (think time) in a cocos2d game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sleep

I'm working on a two player iOS game that is similar to checkers. I'm using cocos2d to create this game.

I want a think time of .5 seconds between when the player's move renders and when the computer's move renders to simulate think time.

The flow of the game is controlled using NSNotification events and looks like this...

Player (computer or human) submits a move -> The board adds the new sprite -> The game controller updates the current player and asks them to submit a move.

I've tried adding usleep(500000) at the end of the board update or the beginning of the game update. What ends up happening is the sprites added in the board update, for the human player, don't show up until after the computer player has submitted his move. So the game waits 500 milliseconds and then updates with both moves.

Is there a way to force the CCLayer to update its child sprites before the usleep, or is there just a better way of adding this think time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you schedule for receiving an update in your controller, you could slip time in the update:(ccTime)dt function.

in your .h

```
float _slipTime;
```

in your .m

```
// with other declaratives

static float THINK_TIME=.5f;


// last line before the stall


_slipTime=0.f; 
[self schedule:@selector(pauseForThink:)];


-(void) pauseForThink:(ccTime) dt {
    _slipTime+=dt;
    if(_slipTime>THINK_TIME) {
        [self unschedule:@selector(pauseForThink:)];
        // trigger here whatever you wanted to accomplish after
        // the think pause.
    }
 }
```

ok, this is simple, but will prevent the main loop from being blocked (this is what happens with your sleep). When running at 60 FPS, the pauseForThink method will be called about 30 times, and cocos will have 30 draw cycles during the pause.